# game controller dongle plugged in to the PC and continue using my PC with it?

Tags: cpu, motherboard

Is it okay for the PC if I leave the game controller dongle plugged in to the PC and continue using my PC with it? Will doing this damage my motherboard?

Comment: Is it ok? Yes. Will it cause any damage? No (physical damage is possible if it's in a position that could be caught/pulled by clothing  etc)

Comment: No, if I plug it in and power on the system with it, is there any problem? And for a long time.

Comment: @Monica do you leave keyboards and mice plugged in for a long time? These dongles are the same except they don't have wires coming out of them.

Answer (score 2):

Dongles are made to be plugged-in and left in place as long as
required.

It's actually the opposite : Unplugging and re-plugging a dongle too
many times, and perhaps with too much force, is dangerous to the
port on which it is branched and to the dongle itself.

You may leave the dongle in place without trouble.
I myself have dongles that stay in place for years without
any problem.